# How to disable automatic rebuild in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I resized the window of `IntelliJ IDEA` or switch to another tab, it automatically rebuild the project. I have 2 modules in the same project, and it only auto rebuilds in 1 module :) . I want to know how to disable this. Thank you very much.

Comment: By default, Idea does not rebuild the projects. Can you share the project in question?

Comment: @NadiaSolovyeva Before that, I changed the config of IntelliJ so that it automatically builds in both modules, but then I turned it off, and it seems to only turn off on one. Now I don't remember how to turn it off :< . I tried to google a few ways but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Probably rebuild is triggered by save action? Please check settings under "Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably rebuild is triggered by save action? Please check settings under "Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings"